# Should one write a custom IndexOutOfRange exception?

Tags: c#, .net

In the process of writing a special collection I utilized the already exisiting `IndexOutOfRangeException` as e.g. a list or array would throw if I were to access an illegal index. Code analysis tells me, however, that this exception should never be thrown by user code, and I fail to see why. If I were to hand out references to this class abstracted by an interface, for example, wouldn't it be a lot better if it just confirmed to the (perceived) norm of throwing the known and beloved `IndexOutOfRangeException` than a custom `IndexNotInRangeException`? What's the motivation behind this rule?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`IndexOutOfRangeException` and `NullReferenceException` should be thrown by the runtime.

If method, which includes an indexer, validates its parameters, it should throw `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` and `ArgumentNullException` instead.

The built in collections, such as [`List<T>` do this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ebtbkkc.aspx):

> **Exceptions:**
>
> `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` -- index is less than 0. -or- index is equal to or greater than Count.